# How to check if record is already exists before creating a new record?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, insert, exists

I'm trying to implement a duplicate topic blocking system to a forum script. Since I'm extremely poor about PHP I though maybe you'd like to help me. Unfortunately, I'm not even sure if I'm trying to edit the right part of the script but here's the code:

```
// If it's a new topic
if ($fid)
{
    $subject = pun_trim($_POST['req_subject']);

    if ($pun_config['o_censoring'] == '1')
        $censored_subject = pun_trim(censor_words($subject));

    if ($subject == '')
        $errors[] = $lang_post['No subject'];
    else if ($pun_config['o_censoring'] == '1' && $censored_subject == '')
        $errors[] = $lang_post['No subject after censoring'];
    else if (pun_strlen($subject) > 70)
        $errors[] = $lang_post['Too long subject'];
    else if ($pun_config['p_subject_all_caps'] == '0' && is_all_uppercase($subject) && !$pun_user['is_admmod'])
        $errors[] = $lang_post['All caps subject'];
}
```

So I'm trying to implement if **$subject** is exist in DB (SELECT * FROM topics WHERE subject), show an error in this format: **$errors[] = $lang_post['Topic is already exist'];**

Thank you.

Comment: Since you've tagged this a `mysql` why not use `COUNT()` or `mysqli_num_rows()` or PDO's `rowCount()`?

Comment: *"`SELECT * FROM topics WHERE subject`"* - You need to add something to that, like `WHERE subject='something'`

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of getting the information that it is in the database or not(here i'm using PDO)

    This is the common code:

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:dbname=db_name', 'username', 'password')
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

### fetch->(PDO::FETCH_NUM)

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("query_to_db");
$sql->execute();
$rows = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
if( $row > 0 ){
   echo "the credentials exists";
}
else{
   // there is nothing like this in the database
}
```

### mysql error code 23000

```
try{
   // connection code above mentioned
   $sql = $conn->prepare("query_to_db");
   $sql->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $e){
  if($e->getCode() == 23000){
     // the credentials exists
  }
  else{
      // doesn't exists
  }
}
```

### rowCount()

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("query_to_db");
$sql->execute();

$count = $sql->rowCount();
if($rowCount > 0){
   //exists in the db
}
else{
   //it doesn't exists in the db
}
```

But the rowCount doesn't in mysql
The php doc says:

> For most databases, PDOStatement::rowCount() does not return the number of rows affected by a SELECT statement. Instead, use PDO::query() to issue a SELECT COUNT(*) statement with the same predicates as your intended SELECT statement, then use DOStatement::fetchColumn() to retrieve the number of rows that will be returned. Your application can then perform the correct action.

I personally prefer the `fetch->(PDO::FETCH_NUM)` as it is more precise than the other.